# Bootstrap collapse section and expand another with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bunch of HTML fields logically separated as such: half the fields reside in: **div id="general"** and the other half reside in: **div id="advanced"**

What I'm trying to implement (and failing) is the following:

The fields in the general div to be shown (by default). A button with the caption "Advanced" shown. And the fields in the advanced div to be hidden.

When this button is clicked, the following should occur:

1. General section collapses hiding all it's fields
2. Advanced section expands showing all it's fields
3. Button caption is changed to "General".

Subsequent clicks toggles the above.

E.g. upon the next click, the advanced section now is hidden, general section now is shown, and button caption changes to "Advanced"

Notes: This seems trivial but being new to web front-end, I can't get this easily. If my div section is incorrect, then scrap it. I suspect I'm on the right track, and just need some jQuery code to collapse and expand divs.

Below are my attempts:

1. I used the Bootstrap collapse plugin with **accordian** markup, but this isn't what I want. It comes close though, but each section has a heading/button. I'd like **one** heading/button to toggle each section in an opposite manner.
2. I used the Bootstrap collapse plugin without the accordian markup, but same result as attempt 1 - two button again.
3. I tried using jQuery to do this dynamically, but can't get the logic (or syntax) correct.

I'm using Bootstrap, but happy to go with jQuery (or JavaScript) solution if it can't be done solely in Bootstrap with the collapse plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JSFiddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19daq1r8/1/)

```
$("#advanced").addClass('hide');
  $(".button").click(function(){
  $("#advanced").toggleClass('hide');
  $("#general").toggleClass('hide');
  if($(this).attr("value") == "Advanced"){
    $(this).attr("value","General");
  }
 else if($(this).attr("value") == "General"){
    $(this).attr("value","Advanced");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jquery by toggling a class on element which decides which fields to be shown.

for e.g. Take an outer `div`, and put general and advanced `div` inside outer `div` and show only the fields based on outer div class like `advanced` using css. And bind a button to toggle the class on the outer div.

Checkout JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/eqhw2mxx/2/